# Multiple OR conditions in CakePHP v1.3.15

Tags: php, cakephp

I have issues with OR conditions in cake php query builder. This will return 0 result.

```
$results = $this->paginate('Did', array('Did.ivr_id LIKE ' => $number . "%",'OR'=>array('Did.did LIKE ' => $number . "%")));
$result = $this->paginate = array(array('Did.did LIKE' => $number . "%"));
$this->set('dids', $results);
```

When i apply condition on simple column it gives accurate result

```
$results = $this->paginate('Did', array('Did.ivr_id LIKE' => $number . "%"));
 $result = $this->paginate = array(array('Did.did LIKE' => $number . "%"));
    $this->set('dids', $results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the conditions that you want to OR inside the OR array.

```
$results = $this->paginate(
    'Did', 
    array(
        'OR'=>array(
             'Did.ivr_id LIKE ' => $number . "%", 
             'Did.did LIKE ' => $number . "%"
         )
    )
);
```